# Excel can not populate array from a discontinued named range

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to populate an array from a named discountinued range and got errors constantly that left me scratching my head. Lastly I tried the same code with cell reference Range and with a named Range that is continous - the same code works.

Here is the code:

```
  Dim vArray() As Variant
  vArray = Range("ContinousRange")


  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
    Debug.Print vArray(i, 1)
  Next
```

It works

```
 Dim vArray() As Variant
  vArray = Range("A1:A4")

  
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
    Debug.Print vArray(i, 1)
  Next
```

also works, but:

```
  Dim vArray() As Variant
  vArray = Range("DiscontinousRange")


  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
    Debug.Print vArray(i, 1)
  Next
```

Does not work.

Why is that so?

Comment: Because the construction logic of assigning a datafield array is built upon a jagged array in the background providing only the same count of elements per background array(s), i.e. Excel/VBA assumes an entire continuous range reference.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the mentioned array? As stated in the above comment, VBA cannot assign a continuous array from a discontinuous range. It loads only the first range area (separated by an empty row from the rest of the range). Depending on what you try doing with the extracted (continuous) array, a function can be built to make it...

Comment: copy each range and paste into a continuous range add into the array and clear contents of created continuous range

Comment: Thanks. I have a form with cells like C2 E2 G2 used for data entry. The idea was that all entry fields are part of a named range and I can populate an array with fields from a named range to finally paste the array into a table. If I add new fields or change the location of entry fields, all I need to do is tweak the named range. 
But as k1drOck suggested I can loop through range and copy it to array.